# Performance of multiple chunked datasets in the same HDF5 file?

Tags: hdf5, h5py

Suppose (i am adding a code example  below) that i create multiple chunked datasets in the same HDF5 file, and i start appending data to each dataset in random order. Since HDF does not know in advance what size to allocate for each dataset, i would think that each append operation (or perhaps a dataset buffer when filled) is directly appended to the HDF5 file. If so, the data of each dataset would be interleaved with the data from the other datasets, and would be spread out in chunks over the entire HDF5 file.

My question is: If the above description is more or less accurate, would this not adversely affect the performance of the read operations done later from that file, and perhaps also the file size if more metadata records are required? And (corrollary), if the option exists to store each dataset in a separate file, would it not be better to do so from the viewpoint of read performance?

Here is an example of how the HDF5 file that i describe in the beginning could be created:

```py
import h5py, numpy as np

dtype1 = np.dtype( [ ('t','f8'), ('T','f8') ] )
dtype2 = np.dtype( [ ('q','i2'), ('Q','f8'), ('R','f8') ] )
dtype3 = np.dtype( [ ('p','f8'), ('P','i8') ] )

with h5py.File('foo.hdf5','w') as f:
    dset1 = f.create_dataset('dset1', (1,), maxshape=(None,), dtype=h5py.vlen_dtype(dtype1))
    dset2 = f.create_dataset('dset2', (1,), maxshape=(None,), dtype=h5py.vlen_dtype(dtype2))
    dset3 = f.create_dataset('dset3', (1,), maxshape=(None,), dtype=h5py.vlen_dtype(dtype3))
    for _ in range(10):
        random_lengths = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=3)

        d1 = np.ones( (random_lengths[0],), dtype=dtype1 )
        dset1[-1] = d1
        dset1.resize( (dset1.shape[0]+1,) )

        d2 = np.ones( (random_lengths[1],), dtype=dtype2 )
        dset2[-1] = d2
        dset2.resize( (dset2.shape[0]+1,) )

        d3 = np.ones( (random_lengths[2],), dtype=dtype3 )
        dset3[-1] = d3
        dset3.resize( (dset3.shape[0]+1,) )
```

I know i could try it both ways (single file multiple datasets or multiple files single datasets) and time it, but the result might depend on the specifics of the example data used and i would rather have a more general answer to this question, and possibly some insight into how HDF5/h5py work internally in this case.

Comment: If I understand, your concern is that each dataset is not contiguous on disk. This is an issue for any file created by any application. The operating system manages disk I/O at the hardware level. As a result, there's no way to guarantee a file or dataset is contiguous on disk when it's allocated. Likely it will be if there is a contiguous free block that is large enough when it's allocated. (You can see this when you derangement a disk.) Computers routinely deal with fragmented files (especially in multi-user systems like an HPC). I/O speed is mostly governed by a drive's read/write speed.

Comment: Right, my concern is the contiguousness of the data on disk. And sure, filesystem-level fragmentation is hard to avoid but i doubt this makes HDF-level fragmentation a non-issue. If that were the case, then why does HDF distinguish between contiguous and chunked storage? Chunked storage is more flexible, so isn't performance the only reason for choosing contiguous? Perhaps this is so because HDF chunks add an extra indirection on top of the filesystem fragmentation, but mainly because i suspect the HDF (or at least h5py) housekeeping overhead is considerably heavier than the filesystem's.